# Best approach to manage related objects in angular?

Tags: angularjs, relational-database

Let's say I have two json objects, one of users and one of accounts, something like:

```js
users = [
  {id: 1, account_id: 1},
  {id: 2, account_id: 2},
  {id: 3, account_id: 1}
]

accounts = [
  {id: 1, name: "administrator"},
  {id: 2, name: "moderator"}
]
```

So I have to loop accross all the users array, and for each of them get the account information. Which is the best way to manage those relationships for accessing them in the markup?  I found the following solutions:

Approach 1: Make a repeat of only one element, so that it's just to filter the elements and to make it available in that part of the markup

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <div ng-repeat="account in getAccountFromId(user.account_id)">
    <!-- now account is available in all this scope to access user.account.name -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Approach 2: Change the way the information is returned from the backend, bringing a json of each user where each json is returned with the account information. But that will repeat a lot of informacion in each json object. Also this implies changing the backend because of angular.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <!-- with this approach I can access here user.account.name -->
</div>
```

Could someone tell me if those approachs are correct? Is there a better way to manage the object relationships in angular?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't like the thought of changing the shape of the data coming from the server, another option is to just map the users to accounts in javascript.

```
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {

  // Pretend that 'users' and 'accounts' here came from an xhr request
  var users = [
    {id: 1, account_id: 1},
    {id: 2, account_id: 2},
    {id: 3, account_id: 1}
  ]

  var accounts = [
    {id: 1, name: "administrator"},
    {id: 2, name: "moderator"}
  ]

  // Map accounts to users
  for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<accounts.length; j++) {
      if (accounts[j].id === users[i].account_id) {
        users[i].account = accounts[j];
      }
    }
  }


});
```

Comment: I see, thanks.So far the approach that I see more adhered to the angular way is changing the shape of the data coming from the server (as you mention), however that will repeat the accounts by each user which for me doesn't seems to have much sense, I consider that angular should count with something to avoid this kind of cases where information has to be repeated. Or may be I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and decided it was not the front-end job to perform data mapping.
So instead of returning on account_id like:

```
users = [
  {id: 1, account_id: 1},
  {id: 2, account_id: 2},
  {id: 3, account_id: 1}
]
```

I extended the model with "account_name" (or whatever the equivalent for me)
Hence the suggested output

```
users = [
  {id: 1, account_id: 1, account_name: "administrator"},
  {id: 2, account_id: 2, account_name: "moderator"},
  {id: 3, account_id: 1, account_name: "administrator"}
]
```

It is slightly redundant but makes your life easier in the UI and doesn't cost much in the server.